# PropertyInfo GetCustomAttributes returning 0 objects

Tags: c#, attributes, propertyinfo

So this is my first time asking here, pls bear with me.
I'm trying to learn how to attach attributes to my objects, but I'm having trouble retrieving them.
So here's my attribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class attr : System.Attribute
{
    public readonly Boolean Required;

    public string formID { get; set; }

    public attr(Boolean required)
    {
        this.Required = required;
    }

    public attr(Boolean required, string formID)
    {
        this.Required = required;
        this.formID = formID;
    }
}
```

Sample of how I "attached" it to a property on one of my objects:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [attr(true, "formRequireField")]
    public int RequiredField { get { return REQUIREDFIELD; } set { REQUIREDFIELD = value; } }
}
```

And code of how I am currently retrieving the attribute:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(MyObject).GetProperties())
{
    Attribute[] attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(property, false);
    foreach (Attribute attribute in attributes)
    {
        if (attribute is attr)
        {
            attr propAttr = (attr)attribute;
            if (propAttr.Required)
            {
                Page.Form.FindControl(propAttr.formID);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've also tried this format

```
    object[] attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(true);
    foreach (object attribute in attributes)
    {
        if (attribute is attr)
        {
            attr propAttr = (attr)attribute;
            if (propAttr.Required)
            {
                Page.Form.FindControl(propAttr.formID);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

both of them returns 0 objects. So I'm not really sure what's happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this - the sample you've given works fine for me. Your code would be easier to read if you followed normal .NET naming conventions. Could you please post a short but complete program which actually fails?

Comment: Sorry for making it hard to read, but that's already the gist of what I want to do, the only thing I can add more is that, that block of code is inside a Page_LoadComplete event handler. I just want to be able to access the attributes of my classes atm. So I have no "complete" program to show yet.

Comment: I wonder if this is a double-declaration issue; are there any occasions where `attributes.Length` is non-zero? I wonder if it is *there*, but as a different formal *type*

Comment: If what you're asking is, if maybe there's some other code block using it and "re-assigning" it, then no, that is the only code block I have that's even using the Reflection class.

Comment: @Jesse: Well I took the code you've given and created a complete program from that with only minimal changes - it worked. You should compare what you've given here with what you've really got. For example, your property is public here - is it public in your real code?

Comment: Yes.. all the code I've typed here is copied and pasted from what I have, the only difference are the names. And that REQUIREDFIELD points to another private property declared as "private int REQUIREDFIELD;".